# Why matplotlib draws me the new graphic superimposing the old one?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm working on `django` project and using the `matplotlib` library. Theoretically I have created a filter where you can choose the day and and "node" that you want to graph and with this information a `python`script is executed that together with pandas and matplotlib creates a graph.

The values ​​of "node" and "day" arrive correctly to the script, and this generates the graphic well. But the only thing wrong is that instead of overwriting the old image (with the previous graphic), draw the new lines on it. Next I show an image of how it looks.

[image]

As you can see, each line is equivalent to a different day, because it has been overlapping the different tests I have done. Can anyone tell me where I fail?

Below I attach code

```
def bateria2(node, day):
    csv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..\\data\\csv\\dataframe.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    mes, anyo = 12, 2019
    new_df = df[(df['Dia'] == day) & (df['Mes'] == mes) & (df['Año'] == anyo) & (df['Node name'] == node)]

    if len(new_df) > 0:
        #os.remove('static\\img\\bateria2.png')
        x = new_df['Hora[UTC]'].tolist()
        y = new_df['Bateria'].tolist()

        title = 'Carga/Descarga de la batería día '+str(day)+'/'+str(mes)+'/'+str(anyo)+' de '+str(node)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.xlabel('Hora [UTC]')
        plt.ylabel('Batería')
        #plt.legend((y)(node))

        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.xticks(x, rotation='vertical')

       plt.savefig('static\\img\\bateria2.png',transparent=True)

        return 1

    else:
        return 0
```

Basically what I'm doing it is to access the .csv file that contains the info, filter according to the data that I want. And if the new dataframe generated has data, create the graph to finally save it.

Regards thank you very much.

Comment: In general for a case like this one would recommend the OO API instead of pyplot.

Comment: Can somebody explain me why a negative vote with no explanation?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest can you put a link please? I write OO API in google but I don't know what I have to found xD

Comment: Much of this may become clear by reading the [Usage guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html). Also [usage-patterns](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html#usage-patterns). An explicit example would be [the CanvasAgg demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/canvasagg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the current figure, `plt.clf()` after your savefig command. This should keep your plots from stacking up on top of each other.